# Open custom Acumatica screen as popup from button on Bills and Adjustments screen

Tags: acumatica

I have a completely custom screen with its own BLC and DACs, and I want to open it as a popup from a button placed on the Bills and Adjustments screen.  I have coded it as follows:

```
public class APInvoiceEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
{

    public PXAction<APInvoice> LaunchOpenSource;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Open Source")]

    protected void launchOpenSource()
    {
        APInvoice apinvoice = (APInvoice)Base.Document.Current;

        if (apinvoice != null)
        {

            //var url = "http://localhost/AcumaticaDB2562/?ScreenId=AC302000&OpenSourceName=Bills+and+Adjustments&DataID=" + apinvoice.RefNbr;
            OpenSourceDataMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<OpenSourceDataMaint>();
            graph.OpenSourceDataHeader.Current = graph.OpenSourceDataHeader.Search<xTACOpenSourceHeader.openSourceName, xTACOpenSourceHeader.dataID>("Bills and Adjustments", apinvoice.RefNbr);

            if (graph.OpenSourceDataHeader.Current != null)
            {
                throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, "Open Source")
                {
                    Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've included all the relevant DACs and BLC for my custom screen in the Class Library project I'm using to customize the 'Bills and Adjustments' screen where I'm adding the button.

The problem I'm having is that I get the following error message when launching the button:

[image]

I've set all the relevant permissions for the screen that uses the OpenSourceDataMaint BLC to 'Delete' in 'Access Right By Role', 'Access Rights By User', and 'Access Rights By Screen'.   Nothing makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, for me, was to put the code (shown below) in a customization window instead of a class library project in Visual Studio.  Since the code needs to have a reference to another published customization, putting it inside an Acumatica code window takes care of this.  There is no reference to the published custom screen customization in my class library project, and this obviously causes issues - and I'm not sure how to handle that.

```
public class APInvoiceEntryExt:PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
{

    public PXAction<APInvoice> LaunchOpenSource;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Open Source")]

    protected void launchOpenSource()
    {
        APInvoice apinvoice = (APInvoice)Base.Document.Current;

        if (apinvoice != null)
        {
            AssistantController.OpenSourceDataMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<AssistantController.OpenSourceDataMaint>();
            graph.OpenSourceDataHeader.Current = graph.OpenSourceDataHeader.Search<AssistantController.xTACOpenSourceHeader.openSourceName
                                                                                  ,AssistantController.xTACOpenSourceHeader.dataID>("Bills and Adjustments", apinvoice.RefNbr);

            throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, "Open Source")
            {
                Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like DataSource is trying to find a node in SiteMap with GraphType equal to full name off your OpenSourceDataMaint class and fails:

```
public class PXBaseDataSource : DataSourceControl, IAttributeAccessor, INamingContainer, ICompositeControlDesignerAccessor, ICommandSource, IPXCallbackHandler, IPXScriptControl, IPXCallbackUpdatable, IPostBackDataHandler
{
    ...

    private static string getFormUrl(Type graphType)
    {
        PXSiteMapNode node = getSiteMapNode(graphType);
        if (node == null)
        {
            throw new PXException(string.Format(ErrorMessages.GetLocal(ErrorMessages.NotEnoughRightsToAccessObject), graphType.Name));
        }
        String url = node.Url;
        //if (url.Contains("unum=")) url = PXUrl.IgnoreQueryParameter(url, "unum");
        return PXUrl.TrimUrl(url);
    }

    ...
}
```

Could you please check if `TypeName` is properly defined for `PXDataSource` inside your custom Aspx page? Also could you please check if your custom Aspx page also exists in Cst_Published folder and if values set for `PXDataSource.TypeName` property are identical inside Pages and Cst_Published folders?

One more thing to check, does the Site Map screen show the right GraphName for your custom screen? - would be beneficial if you can provide a screenshot for verification.

If possible, please provide your customization package, that can be published locally (even with compiled assembly) - this would greatly speed up the investigation process.

Comment: Ruslan - I've found a solution, which is to put the code in a code window in the customization manager instead of in a class library project referenced by the website.  I'm not sure how to do it as a class library project, as it needs to have a reference to a published customization (our custom screen, BLC, and DACs).  When you put it in a code window in Acumatica, our published custom / new screen customization is already there so the reference is valid.